# How to top align some text with a logo in titlingpage (memoir)?

Tags: memoir

Here is a MWE of my problem:

```
\documentclass[article, openany, a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\makepagestyle{mytitlestyle}
\makeevenhead{mytitlestyle}{\scshape University of Copenhagen}{}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\makeoddhead{mytitlestyle}{\scshape University of Copenhagen}{}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\makeevenfoot{mytitlestyle}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{mytitlestyle}{}{}{}

\title{My Thesis}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlingpage}
\aliaspagestyle{titlingpage}{mytitlestyle}

\begin{center}
\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\thetitle
\end{center}

\end{titlingpage}

\end{document}
```

By default the header contents appear bottom aligned. The logo is supposed to be bigger than the "University of Copenhagen" text and should be top aligned.

Comment: Exactly how large is the logo? We of course do not have the image, so how about updating your code replacing the image with a black square.

Comment: On the other hand, this has nothing to do with alignment in the headers. Both texts stand on the baseline, there is no option to say align this such that the top to this text aligns with the top of this image.

Comment: BTW 2: is it a requirement at KU that the university name and logo is on all pages or is this just a title page design? In the later case I would not use headers to make that line.

Comment: @daleif I got a better description of the template yesterday. The logo does not appear on all pages, only on the title page. So, I dropped the header idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the header for that purpose is not necessary at all (and wrong). You can use `adjustbox` for aligning the logo on top.

```
\documentclass[article, openany, a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\unilogo}{%
  \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
}

\title{My Thesis}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlingpage}
\centering

\vspace*{-2cm} % or whatever

\textsc{University of Copenhagen}
\hfill
\unilogo

\bigskip % or whatever

\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\thetitle

\end{titlingpage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. I reached the same conclusion, i.e. it's wrong to use the header for such a purpose. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: @remus, doesn't the KU design also include the red line? Plus the logo it on the left of the name not to the right (though I do not know exactly which KU logo you are refering to)

Comment: @daleif I'm using this logo: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0f/University_of_Copenhagen_Seal.svg

Comment: THere ought to be some official place to down load that on KU (I'm AT AU, so know no details about KU).

Comment: @daleif I'm doing this template for a friend who is in KU. I'm from DTU, so I don't know their rules. Anyway, we changed the logo to something else so probably you're right with the red line.

Comment: I just noticed yesterday that sometimes thye have it on the left and some times on the right. I would swear that I've also seen this in green...